# Get json value based on dynamic key mapping for partial path

Tags: node.js, arrays, json, key-value

I am trying to get the values of a key in a json file, but there are several issues that I need to solve.

1. The key of the JSON is dynamic - I have another JSON in which I am given the path of the key inside the JSON.
   For example, I have a json file that contains the following mapping:

   {
   "addressesPath":"personal.addresses"
   }

This tells me that the value I am looking for is inside another key, called personal.
The JSON will look like this:

```
{
     "username": "X1",
     "id":"1X",
      "type": "patron",
      "group": "students",
      "personal": {
          "lastname": "lname",
          "firstname": "fname",
          "email": "test@test.test",
          "phone": "1-111-111-1111",
          "mobilePhone": "(111)111-1111",
          "birthDate": "1979-01-23T00:00:00.000+0000",
          "addresses":
              {
                  "countryId": "US",
                  "addressLine1": "1111 Brannon Ford Suite 111",
                  "city": "Kettering",
                  "region": "MA",
                  "postalCode": "11111-1111",
                  "primaryAddress": true
              }
      }
}
```

So for example if the JSON is "user", what I want to get is user.personal.addresses

How can I translate "user.personal.addresses" to "users.+dynamic"?
I tried doing it just like that, but it doesn't seem to work with any type of string I extract from the mapping json file.

2. I have an issue because I don't know if the location I am getting is a single value or an array of values.
   For example, the JSON could look like this:

   {
   "username": "X1",
   "id":"1X",
   "type": "patron",
   "group": "students",
   "personal": {
   "lastname": "lname",
   "firstname": "fname",
   "email": "test@test.test",
   "phone": "1-111-111-1111",
   "mobilePhone": "(111)111-1111",
   "birthDate": "1979-01-23T00:00:00.000+0000",
   "addresses":[
   {
   "countryId": "US",
   "addressLine1": "1111 Brannon Ford Suite 111",
   "city": "Kettering",
   "region": "MA",
   "postalCode": "11111-1111",
   "primaryAddress": true
   }, {
   "countryId": "US",
   "addressLine1": "1112 Brannon Ford Suite 112",
   "city": "Kettering",
   "region": "IL",
   "postalCode": "11112-1112",
   "primaryAddress": false
   }
   ]
   }
   }

Which means I need to determine the structure of the data I am going to get, whether it is an array or not.
Can I do this by checking if the result is a string or object? I know that arrays from JSON files are read as objects in node js.

Comment: How do you retrieve values from json? Do you use JSON.parse?

Comment: @RadicalEdward I use a function I built that returns the element as though it was parsed, yes. It is not a string. I can get values using the regular structure, like "users.personal". I just have an issue because the path I need is dynamic, so I can't just write "users.personal" in the code. It could be "users.personal", but it can also be "users.info.personal" or "users.personalinfo". I only know the path by getting the value from the mapping json file (the mapping itself is saved as a string variable).

Comment: Then follow simple thing. `users['user']['personal']['address']` will accept variables inside `[..]`, you can pass variables as well which could be `address` `personal` , etc.

Below answer would help.

Comment: @RadicalEdward Interesting. I tried users.[addressMap] but kept getting error messages. I'll try it this way and see if it works.
Mohammad also gave me a function that solves the other issue I had to deal with, but now I want to see if this system works, as it might be useful for the future.

Comment: Also mention error and value of addresssMap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something like that
With three examples

```js
let object = {
  "group": "students",
  "personal": {
    "addresses": {
      "countryId": "US",
    }
  }
}

let test1 = checkObject(object, "personal.addresses")
console.log(test1);

let object2 = {
  "test": {
    "test_deep": [
      {
        "countryId": "US",
        "addressLine1": "1111 Brannon Ford Suite 111"
      },
      {
        "countryId": "US",
        "addressLine1": "1112 Brannon Ford Suite 112",
      }
    ]
  }
}

let test2 = checkObject(object2, "test.test_deep")
console.log(test2);

let object3 = {
  "test": {
    "test_deep": "test"
  }
}

let test3 = checkObject(object3, "test.test_deep")
console.log(test3);

function checkObject(object, addressesPath) {
  let addres = addressesPath.split(".")
  let item = object
  for (let index = 0; index < addres.length; index++) {
    if (typeof item[addres[index]] != 'undefined') {
      item = item[addres[index]]
    } else {
      item = null
      break
    }
  }

  return {
    type: typeof item,
    is_array: Array.isArray(item),
    data: item
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, that works perfectly!
I will need to study exactly how it works, but I just tested it in my own code and it returns exactly what I was looking for!
Thanks!